# Restricting usb usage

Tags: usb, restricted-access

I'm using Ubuntu as a server with windows XP clients. I need to block USB ports for clients (xp) through ubuntu from accessing storage media without affecting the USB I/O devices. Is there any centralized way to control USB access on XP clients from Ubuntu ?.
Is it possible to do this with any third party apps ?

Comment: If the question is already answered please provide me the link. It ill be more helpful.

Comment: When a question is closed as a duplicate, the link is always in the banner at the top of the question, immediately to the right of the up and down arrows. For convenience, this question has been closed as a duplicate of [How do I restrict USB access?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/303455/how-do-i-restrict-usb-access).